# How truthful was Jean Valjean when he told Javert in the hospital "In mercy's name, three days are all I need. Then I'll return, I pledge my word."

Tags: les-miserables

In *Les Miserable*, the part where Jean Valjean tells Javert in the hospital "In mercy's name, three days are all I need. Then I'll return, I pledge my word." is the part when he just assured Fantine that he would take care of her child Cosette.

I regard him (by this time) as a very honest and righteous person, who lives by his words. But how truthful do you think he was when he pledged to return after three days, so he could take Cosette out of the inn?

How could he fulfill his vow to Fantine if 3 days later he would go back to jail and Cosette would end up even not having a house anymore but out on the street?

Was he actually lying to get away?